# Python; what does myLink = data["items"][0]["link"] do?

Tags: python, json

What does **myLink = data["items"][0]["link"]** do in the code snippet below? I get that it says; if my json data structure has the key "items", but what does the **[0]["link"]** part do?

```
response = requests.get(resUrl)
data = response.json()

if data.has_key("items"):
    myLink = data["items"][0]["link"]
else:
    myLink = "no link found"
```

Comment: Find the dictionary at the 0th index of the list stored against the "items" key and get the value stored against the "link" key of that dictionary. You should be able to print the json response and follow the logic.

Comment: the *items* key is an array, the [0] gets the first index and then look for the *link* and return it.

Comment: It gets the link from the 0th index of the list stored against the items if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {'items':[{'link':'xxx'}, {'link':'yyy'}, {'link':'zzz'}]}
```

the above dict() object have an inner array of dict() objects as value or the key `'items'.`

To obtain this value, `data["items"]` works and for parsing the elements in the array `[0]['link']` work.

```
["items"] get the value of 'items' key # O/P [{'link':'xxx'}, {'link':'yyy'}, {'link':'zzz'}]
["items"][0] first index of the array # O/P {'link':'xxx'}
["items"][0]['link'] key of the first index #O/P 'xxx'
```

I would like to appreciate your courage for asking the basic question which many hesitate to ask and flunks in mere future.

Cheers!